# Android Bluetooth Low Energy - Can't get data correctly from BluetoothGattCharacteristic by bytes operations

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hy everyone, 
I'm working on an Android App using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). I'm connected to my device, and I subscrided to a characteristic. I correctly receive my notifications and data. Then I would like to get different information from this `BluetoothGattCharacteristic`.

Here is my problem : in my BluetoothGattCharacteristic, I want to receive two information, so I used a bytes mask to get these data. The data are stored in a unsignedInt32.

Here is my code to get the data I want, where characteristic is my `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` value :

```
int value_one = (characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32, 0) & 0x03FFFFFF);

int value_two = ((characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32, 0) & 0xFC000000)>>26);
```

To give you some details, I receive correctly value_one, but about value_two, I reveice my data until it reach 31 then i start to get negative data. 
Like this `0,1,2,3 ... 30,31, -32,-31,-30,-29 ... etc`

I'm stuck in this problem. If you can help me it would be amazing !

Thank you for your time and help.